# Alternate way to popup FB login in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is there any other way to check the username and password of the FB from iPhone with out using FBDialog? like using webservice (to send the username and password to the FB server and get the auth_token and session_key)

Sri

Comment: You have to use the facebook sdk of iphone.
Then you can access all data of the user.
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/

Answer (score 1):

For security/phishing reasons, collecting the user's password directly is a violation of the Facebook terms of service. You are required to use Facebook's dialogs for this.